# dotNet компиляция в бинарник

Tags: .net

Где-то краем уха я слышал, что .NET код можно компилировать не в MSIL(Microsoft Intermediate Language), а прямиком в бинарник. Вроде как только средствами Visual Studio(а не Mono).

- Возможно ли это или Я ошибаюсь?
- Компилировать в бинарник умеет только VS или Mono тоже?
- Компиляция в машинный код дает выигрыш в производительности относительно компиляции в IL?

Буду рад получить ответ даже не один из поставленных вопросов.
*P.S.: Сори, если нарушил правила портала, впихнув сюда сразу три вопроса.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Это возможно с помощью утилиты [NGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).
- Маловероятно, что есть что-то подобное NGen.exe, для Lixux.
- Компиляция дает выигрыш во времени загрузки, но не дает существенного выигрыша во время работы, так как все равно приложение работает на основе .NET и используется JIT.

Статья на MSDN: [Компиляция MSIL в машинный код](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ht8ecch6(v=VS.90).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Возможность предварительной компиляции в машинный код .Net сборок присутствует, для таких целей существует Ngen (подробнее [на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx)):

> Генератор образов в машинном коде (Ngen.exe) — это средство повышения быстродействия управляемых приложений. Ngen.exe создает образы в машинном коде, представляющие собой файлы, содержащие компилированный специфический для процессора машинный код, и устанавливает их в кэш образов в машинном коде на локальном компьютере. Среда выполнения может использовать образы в машинном коде, находящиеся в кэше, вместо использования JIT-компилятора для компиляции исходной сборки.

Однако для выполнения необходимо присутствие установленного .Net фреймворка и самой сборки, для которой выполняется прекомпиляция.